# How to verify a deployed contract on etherscan

Tags: etherscan, verify

I would love to get some help with this as I'm wracking my brain with how to get this done.

I have gone through this link to verify my contract:
https://etherscan.io/verifyContract

I am puzzled with where to start, I created a Wallet Contract in Ethereum Wallet, and not sure where to gather this info to paste in there.

If someone can help me I would gladly tip some ETH to make it worth your time to walk a newb through the process.

Comment: First of all you don't need to give nothing for help you, so with the problem can you specifie more waht you need to know or what you don't found in the Ethereum Wallet?